# Why is Primary Key not present at the end of Unique Key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.7, unique-constraint

I have a table with following definition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `g` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `b_UNIQUE` (`b`),
  KEY `single` (`c`),
  KEY `double` (`d`,`e`),
  KEY `triple` (`f`,`g`,`h`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

For some queries when I check optimizer trace I notice key parts for indices.

For example:

```
{
  "index": "single",
  "usable": true,
  "key_parts": [
    "c",
    "a"
  ]
},
{
  "index": "double",
  "usable": true,
  "key_parts": [
    "d",
    "e",
    "a"
  ]
}
```

Notice for indices `single` and `double` the key part contains the Primary Key `a` at the end. That is what `InnoDB` says. So thats good.

```
{
  "index": "b_UNIQUE",
  "usable": true,
  "key_parts": [
    "b"
  ]
}
```

But as seen in above snippet, the `b_Unique` key does not contain primary key `a` as the final key part. Is it really not present and pointer to record is present? What implications does this have with respect to query optimization and Page reorganisation?

EDIT 1: It seems to be present in MySQL 8.0 version. It is highly likely to be present in MySQL version 5.7 as well. So require a way to check its presence in this version.

Answer (score 2):

> But as seen in above snippet, the b_Unique key does not contain primary key a as the final key part.

It is a snippet problem.

> ```
> show index from test
> ```
>
> ```
> Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression
> :---- | ---------: | :------- | -----------: | :---------- | :-------- | ----------: | -------: | :----- | :--- | :--------- | :------ | :------------ | :------ | :---------
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | a           | A         |           0 |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | b_UNIQUE |            1 | b           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | single   |            1 | c           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | double   |            1 | d           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | double   |            2 | e           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            1 | f           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            2 | g           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            3 | h           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null
> ```
>
> ```
> show extended index from test
> ```
>
> ```
> Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression
> :---- | ---------: | :------- | -----------: | :---------- | :-------- | ----------: | -------: | :----- | :--- | :--------- | :------ | :------------ | :------ | :---------
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | a           | A         |           0 |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | DB_TRX_ID   | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | DB_ROLL_PTR | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            4 | b           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            5 | c           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            6 | d           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            7 | e           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            8 | f           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            9 | g           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |           10 | h           | A         |        null |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | b_UNIQUE |            1 | b           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          0 | b_UNIQUE |            2 | a           | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | single   |            1 | c           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | single   |            2 | a           | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | double   |            1 | d           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | double   |            2 | e           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | double   |            3 | a           | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            1 | f           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            2 | g           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            3 | h           | A         |           0 |     null | null   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null      
> test  |          1 | triple   |            4 | a           | A         |        null |     null | null   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | null
> ```

Comment: Why am I getting `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'extended index from test' at line 1` when I try to run `show extended index from test;`?

Comment: @ArunRajagopal You forget to specify your server version. It seems it is too ancient.

Comment: Yes checked the documentation. It is available only from `8.0`. I am using `5.7`. Is there any other way I can check extended index details in `MySQL 5.7`? Somewhere in Information Schema?

Comment: @ArunRajagopal Sorry, I don't know how to do it on your server version.

Comment: (And if you have a `FULLTEXT` index, there will be another column.)